# I can't create a function in PGSQL via concat to get data in a loop over all json

Tags: json, postgresql

I can't create a function in PGSQL via concat to get data in a loop over all json.
But I want to get data from the database for this json in a loop through all the data from metrics->values->avg and med
Let's say from http_req_duration{scenario:find}->metrics->values->avg and med

JSON structure is like this.

```
{
    "root_group": {
        "name": "",
        "path": "",
        "id": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
        "groups": [],
        "checks": [
            {
                "name": "is joint 200",
                "path": "::is joint 200",
                "id": "ae8070af06d4849b5a73c0ea09c2238e",
                "passes": 12122,
                "fails": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "is status 200 find-all",
                "path": "::is status 200 find-all",
                "id": "bae23285599010636d5dcbc6311a79b6",
                "passes": 73852,
                "fails": 0
            },
            {
                "passes": 30874,
                "fails": 3395,
                "name": "is status 200 conditional",
                "path": "::is status 200 conditional",
                "id": "8f2e67a51bef6111123e1aa04f006a1c"
            }
        ]
    },
    "options": {
        "summaryTrendStats": [
            "avg",
            "min",
            "med",
            "max",
            "p(90)",
            "p(95)"
        ],
        "summaryTimeUnit": "",
        "noColor": false
    },
    "state": {
        "isStdOutTTY": false,
        "isStdErrTTY": false,
        "testRunDurationMs": 345617.874234
    },
    "metrics": {
        "data_received": {
            "contains": "data",
            "values": {
                "count": 106316067,
                "rate": 307611.59918488155
            },
            "type": "counter"
        },
        "http_req_waiting{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=2": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=2": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_blocked{scenario:find}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 0.001723,
                "med": 0.004228,
                "max": 9.42929,
                "p(90)": 0.005511,
                "p(95)": 0.006082,
                "avg": 0.00487203336402536
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=8": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=7": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0
            }
        },
        "http_req_waiting{scenario:con}": {
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "med": 0.936649,
                "max": 99.55948,
                "p(90)": 2.4427536,
                "p(95)": 4.682848199999995,
                "avg": 1.5082012875777009,
                "min": 0.541066
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=5.8": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend"
        },
        "http_req_receiving{scenario:find}": {
            "values": {
                "max": 15.097094,
                "p(90)": 0.066625,
                "p(95)": 0.08054044999999994,
                "avg": 0.05262911127660761,
                "min": 0.013265,
                "med": 0.046247
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time"
        },
        "iterations{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "values": {
                "count": 1201,
                "rate": 3.4749360190406846
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "count>0": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "counter",
            "contains": "default"
        },
        "vus_max": {
            "type": "gauge",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "value": 249,
                "min": 114,
                "max": 249
            }
        },
        "dropped_iterations": {
            "type": "counter",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "count": 26803,
                "rate": 77.55096596032263
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:find}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 1.3326389626144177,
                "min": 0.446288,
                "med": 0.7976185,
                "max": 84.594877,
                "p(90)": 2.3167139000000017,
                "p(95)": 3.87368795
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=5": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 5": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=3.5": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:con}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 612.0240284,
                "avg": 603.5558696238289,
                "min": 15.970423,
                "med": 607.863974,
                "max": 657.394861,
                "p(90)": 610.6949792
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=615": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=620": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "checks": {
            "type": "rate",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "rate": 0.9717655081792703,
                "passes": 116848,
                "fails": 3395
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "med": 0.022442,
                "max": 3.47231,
                "p(90)": 0.030297,
                "p(95)": 0.032682,
                "avg": 0.02284295450878623,
                "min": 0.006382
            }
        },
        "http_req_receiving{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending{scenario:con}": {
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0.02357408380752288,
                "min": 0.008426,
                "med": 0.023204,
                "max": 0.356089,
                "p(90)": 0.031048,
                "p(95)": 0.033433
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend"
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 1.9972035187343873,
                "min": 1.141805,
                "med": 1.685224,
                "max": 16.105638,
                "p(90)": 2.205132,
                "p(95)": 5.332459
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=7": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=3": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=7": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=8": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{expected_response:true}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "max": 99.649419,
                "p(90)": 2.3154703000000003,
                "p(95)": 3.958521399999999,
                "avg": 1.3774202878354742,
                "min": 0.446288,
                "med": 0.848834
            }
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:cachUpdate}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(90)": 1.945155,
                "p(95)": 5.37025,
                "avg": 1.9303337557073827,
                "min": 1.010889,
                "med": 1.637776,
                "max": 13.960856
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=7": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:join}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(90)": 1.8037868999999997,
                "p(95)": 3.272206999999999,
                "avg": 1.1918320848869903,
                "min": 0.449915,
                "med": 0.740105,
                "max": 76.250356
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 5": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=2.5": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_receiving{scenario:cachUpdate}": {
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend"
        },
        "iterations{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "counter",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "count": 1,
                "rate": 0.0028933688751379555
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "count>0": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 45": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 45": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=45": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=45": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_connecting": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0.0003791068253453424,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 9.383985,
                "p(90)": 0
            }
        },
        "http_req_receiving": {
            "values": {
                "avg": 0.052778179752667034,
                "min": 0.013265,
                "med": 0.046778,
                "max": 15.117281,
                "p(90)": 0.067176,
                "p(95)": 0.08071009999999995
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time"
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:join}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 601.8235918496938,
                "min": 11.453644,
                "med": 606.0548980000001,
                "max": 640.327367,
                "p(90)": 608.9491829,
                "p(95)": 610.87953835
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=615": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=620": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "iterations{scenario:cachUpdate}": {
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "count": 6001,
                "rate": 17.363106619702872
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "count>0": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "counter"
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:find}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 602.7191305882533,
                "min": 12.527132,
                "med": 607.5824175,
                "max": 659.325018,
                "p(90)": 610.23609,
                "p(95)": 611.26768395
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <=610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=615": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=620": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_waiting{scenario:cachUpdate}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=2": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=2": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_blocked{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_blocked{scenario:eventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_receiving{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0
            }
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "thresholds": {
                "max>=0": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 41518.762811,
                "med": 41518.762811,
                "max": 41518.762811,
                "p(90)": 41518.762811,
                "p(95)": 41518.762811,
                "avg": 41518.762811
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending{scenario:cachUpdate}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_tls_handshaking": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0
            }
        },
        "iterations": {
            "type": "counter",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "rate": 373.091236342414,
                "count": 128947
            }
        },
        "http_req_blocked{scenario:join}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 0.006021,
                "avg": 0.004797885249958743,
                "min": 0.001803,
                "med": 0.004248,
                "max": 0.44682,
                "p(90)": 0.0055209
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:con}": {
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 5": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=3.5": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=6.5": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 1.585340762963596,
                "min": 0.584217,
                "med": 1.014234,
                "max": 99.649419,
                "p(90)": 2.5346404,
                "p(95)": 4.764954199999999
            }
        },
        "http_req_receiving{scenario:con}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0.05356539157839449,
                "min": 0.014327,
                "med": 0.048171,
                "max": 15.117281,
                "p(90)": 0.06851080000000001,
                "p(95)": 0.08132260000000001
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_blocked{scenario:cachUpdate}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.loaddt_get_metrics(_id integer)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
_row text;
_output text;
begin
for _row in (select json_object_keys(l.info->'metrics') from loaddt l  where l.id = _id) loop -- Правильный получение ключей

  _output = concat((select sub.metric->'values'->>'p(90)' as p90, sub.metric->'values'->>'p(95)' as p95, sub.metric->'values'->>'med' as med, sub.metric->'values'->>'avg'
  as avg), '|')  from (select (l.info->'metrics'->>_row)::json as metric from loaddt l ) sub;
end loop;
return _output;
end;
$function$
;
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: subquery must return only one column
  Where: PL/pgSQL function loaddt_get_metrics(integer) line 8 at assignment

OR

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: subquery must return only one column
  Where: PL/pgSQL function loaddt_get_metrics(integer) line 7 at assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what are you trying to achieve, but maybe simple sql would suffice.

Assume you have table `loaddt`:

```
create table loaddt(
    id int primary key,
    info json
);
```

Then you can replace your loop with a query:

```
create or replace function loaddt_get_metrics(_id integer)
 returns table(key text, output text)
 language sql
as $function$
select 
    js.key as  metric, 
    concat_ws(
        '|',
        js.value->'values'->>'p(90)',
        js.value->'values'->>'p(95)',
        js.value->'values'->>'med',
        js.value->'values'->>'avg') as output
from loaddt as t, json_each(t.info->'metrics') as js 
where t.id = _id
$function$
;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks brother, this is what I needed, I got the information from json, thanks again))
I tried to loop through the entire json and get information on all the metrics that contain avg, med, so that later I can try to compare them and get the percentage difference for each metric

You helped me with the basic problem of getting this data, thanks a lot again